# How to restore default action (possibility of leaving without confirmation) after use a "beforeunload"

Tags: javascript

How to restore default action (possibility of leaving without confirmation) after use a "beforeunload".

Globally I using:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function( event ) {
    event.returnValue = "Some text";
});
```

but I would like that after pressing one particular button there was no message and the page loaded normally.

```
        $("#button").on("click", function() {
            window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function( event ) {
                event.returnValue = false;
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log(event);
            });

            window.location.href = "https://google.com/";
        });
```

or

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

I tried to do it in several ways but I can't do it.

Comment: Since you added the handler using `addEventListener`, you should probably use its counterpart `removeEventListener` to remove it again.

Comment: @misorude something like this `window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", function( event ) {
     event.returnValue = "Wprowadzone zmiany mogą nie zostać zapisane.";
    });` ?

Comment: No, you need to pass the reference to the same handler function instance. With this, you would be creating a _different_ function. https://medium.com/@DavideRama/removeeventlistener-and-anonymous-functions-ab9dbabd3e7b

Comment: Ok, now everything works :) Thanks @misorude